# Creating a new layer from query results

Tags: shapefile, arcobjects, c#

Newbie in ArcObjects programming. Using C#. Developing a desktop application.

I need to join 2 tables:

- POI layer which is a Point layer and
- a parcel layer which is a Polygon

Where

```
POI.HouseNo = Parcel.UNIT_ID
```

and then **create a new Shapefile** which has only the 4 fields:

- POIName,
- POIType,
- HouseNo (all from POI layer attributes),
- ParcelName (all from Parcel Layer attributes).

The user selects the POI Layer and the Parcel layer from combo boxes.

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
IFeatureWorkspace featureWorkspace;
IQueryDef queryDef = featureWorkspace.CreateQueryDef();
queryDef.Tables = cboPOI.Text + "," + cboParcel.Text;
queryDef.SubFields = cboPOI.Text + ".Name," + cboPOI.Text + ".Type," + cboPOI.Text +".HouseNo," + cboParcel.Text + ".ParcelName";
queryDef.WhereClause = cboPOI.Text + ".HouseNo =" + cboParcel.Text+ ".UNIT_ID";
```

Hope I'm on the right track.
Now I need to **run this query and get the output to a new Shapefile**. How can I do this?

please help.

Answer (score 2):

The [AO-API has got an example](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/arcobjects/esrigeodatabase/IQueryDef_Example.htm). This would mean that you would have to extent your code by the following lines:

```
IFeatureDataset featureDataset = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureQuery("MyJoin", queryDef);
IFeatureClassContainer featureClassContainer = (IFeatureClassContainer)featureDataset;
IFeatureClass featureClass = featureClassContainer.get_ClassByName("MyJoin");
```

And just assign that feture class to a feature layer. Assuming you really want to create a new shapefile in the filesystem, you can export the created feature class with a geoprocessor like [FeatureClassToShapefile](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/0047/00470000325w000000.htm).